# Is the a module that will allow me to quickly switch from administrator to user?

Tags: 7

Is there a module that will allow me to quickly switch from the administrator view of my site to the user's view?

I currently use Firefox to login as admin and IE to login as a user. This arrangement works, but is very, very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) module.

**Part of description :**

> The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with
> enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no
> password required). That person can switch back to their own user
> account at any time.
>
> This is helpful for site developers when trying to determine what a
> client, logged in as themselves, might see when logged into the site.
>
> The masquerade module is designed as a tool for site designers and
> site administrators. While masquerading, a field is set on the $user
> object, and a menu item appears allowing the user to switch back.
> Database log (watchdog) entries are made any time a user masquerades
> or stops masquerading as another user.

Comment: Wonderful! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @SamStamport your welcome my friend, I am here to help drupalists ;)